# How to Implement different backgrounds on scroll

Tags: html, css

I wanted to replicate the effects as shown here -

<strike>https://allods.my.com/en/news</strike> (not this one, sorry)

http://bit.do/b2692

https://www.google.co.in/sheets/about

Ignoring all the animations, i wanted to know how can we implement multiple different backgrounds as one scrolls down the page.

PS. I am a complete beginner, i prefer to have an HTML/CSS solution only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try to add position fixed property to Your background , it should help.

```css
body,
html,
main {
  /* important */
  height: 100%;
}
.fixed-bg {
  min-height: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
}
.fixed-bg.bg-1 {
  background-image: url("https://c7.staticflickr.com/8/7052/6803328782_432e1dd481_b.jpg");
}
.fixed-bg.bg-2 {
  background-image: url("https://imagesus-ssl.homeaway.com/mda01/b8b73d34-98e2-4633-ab05-6797a99bcf2e.1.10/Cocoa-Beach-Pier-with-Disney-cruise-ship-in-background.jpg");
}
.fixed-bg.bg-3 {
  background-image: url("http://static.fly4free.pl/s/2015/4/f/f6dc42b71e7ef2336edbfbc8c9124684.jpeg");
}
.fixed-bg.bg-4 {
  background-image: url("http://coachhouse.com.au/default/assets/File/kayak.jpg");
}
.scrolling-bg {
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="fixed-bg bg-1">
    <h1><!-- title goes here--></h1>
  </div>

  <div class="scrolling-bg cd-color-2">
    <div class="container">
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolore incidunt suscipit similique, dolor corrupti cumque qui consectetur autem laborum fuga quas ipsam doloribus sequi...
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="fixed-bg bg-2">
    <h1><!-- title goes here --></h1>
  </div>

  <div class="scrolling-bg color-2">
    <div class="container">
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolore incidunt suscipit similique, dolor corrupti cumque qui consectetur autem laborum fuga quas ipsam doloribus sequi...
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="fixed-bg bg-3">
    <h1><!-- title goes here --></h1>
  </div>

  <div class="scrolling-bg color-2">
    <div class="container">
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolore incidunt suscipit similique, dolor corrupti cumque qui consectetur autem laborum fuga quas ipsam doloribus sequi...
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="fixed-bg bg-4">
    <h1><!-- title goes here --></h1>
  </div>

  <div class="scrolling-bg color-2">
    <div class="container">
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolore incidunt suscipit similique, dolor corrupti cumque qui consectetur autem laborum fuga quas ipsam doloribus sequi...
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
```

Div after div approach :

```css
body,
html,
main {
  /* important */
  height: 100%;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}
.container{
position:absolute;

}

.fixed-bg {
  min-height: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  
}
.fixed-bg.bg-1 {
  background-image: url("https://c7.staticflickr.com/8/7052/6803328782_432e1dd481_b.jpg");

  
}
.fixed-bg.bg-2 {
  background-image: url("https://imagesus-ssl.homeaway.com/mda01/b8b73d34-98e2-4633-ab05-6797a99bcf2e.1.10/Cocoa-Beach-Pier-with-Disney-cruise-ship-in-background.jpg");
  
  
}
.fixed-bg.bg-3 {
  background-image: url("http://static.fly4free.pl/s/2015/4/f/f6dc42b71e7ef2336edbfbc8c9124684.jpeg");
}
.fixed-bg.bg-4 {
  background-image: url("http://coachhouse.com.au/default/assets/File/kayak.jpg");
}
.scrolling-bg {
  min-height: 100%;
 
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="fixed-bg bg-1">
    <div class="container"><!-- content goes here--></div>
    </div>
  
  <div class="fixed-bg bg-2">
   <div class="container"><!-- content goes here--></div>
  </div>

  
  <div class="fixed-bg bg-3">
   <div class="container"><!-- content goes here--></div>
  </div>

  
  <div class="fixed-bg bg-4">
   <div class="container"><!-- content goes here--></div>
  </div>

 
</main>
```

Comment: Your effect looks like one wallpaper gradually coming over another.......please take a look at the 2nd and 3rd link...............i want different wallpapers coming one by one...

Comment: please check my edit

Answer (score 1):

So you are looking for a parallax effect, there is a number of plugins for that. I recently used http://pixelcog.github.io/parallax.js/ which worked out well for me.

It's very simple to use it. You said you want an HTML / css solution for this, but i don't think you can do it without javascript. If someone else knows the alternative without javascript i'd like to see it also. But even if you don't know much about javascript you can use this plugin, just follow the instructions on the link i provided.

The plugin requires jquery to work!

Comment: why would the second link require parallax effect, can i not stack the background wallpapers one after the other for the effect... (see 2nd link) ... @Vlatko Murković

Comment: On the 2nd link there is no parallax effect like on 3rd link. You can just make div's then and put background-image css property on each one of them instead of using background-image on the body tag.